# create binary value if a value in a column exists in another list in pandas quickly

Tags: pandas, list

I have a data frame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','c','d','f'],'col2':[1,2,3,4]})
```

and want to create a new column that is `1/0`  if the value in col1 is an element in a list, `lst=['a','b','c']`

I am using:

```
df['in_lst']=df.col1.apply(lambda x: int(x in lst))
```

to get

```
    col1    col2    in_lst
0   a       1       1
1   c       2       1
2   d       3       0
3   f       4       0
```

my actual dataframe in 100k rows, and my list length is 1k.

This is extremely slow at the moment, is there a way I can speed this up?

Any suggestions